# will using "+" preserve my order in a map ? No right?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
scala>  var test2 : Map[String , String] = Map("a"->"b","c"->"d")
test2: Map[String,String] = Map(a -> b, c -> d)

test2 = test2 + ("e"->"f" , "g"->"h")
test2: Map[String,String] = Map(a -> b, c -> d, e -> f, g -> h)
```

And so on. I want to know that Map is not supposed to preserve order of insertion [For that purpose we have LinkedHashMap]then why are the results showing preservation of order? is this a mere coincidence or there is more than meets the eye ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's coincidence that holds only for the first 4 items.

```
val m = Map('a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2, 'c' -> 3, 'd' -> 4)
// m: immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4)

m + ('e' -> 5)
// immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(e -> 5, a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4)
```

The reason is that there is a special optimized implementations for small maps which indeed preserve insertion order (e.g. [append to Map of one pair](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L109:L111)), but once you cross this border it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Coincidental. The ordering *may* be preserved, but preservation of ordering is not *guaranteed* and should not be relied upon. In fact, one should not consider maps to be ordered at all.